# How to change display text in django admin foreignkey dropdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, foreign-keys, django-admin

I have a task list, with ability to assign users. So I have foreignkey to User model in the database. However, the default display is username in the dropdown menu, I would like to display full name (first last) instead of the username. If the foreignkey is pointing to one of my own classes, I can just change the **str** function in the model, but User is a django authentication model, so I can't easily change it directly right?

Anyone have any idea how to accomplish this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new ModelForm for your Task model, which will display the list of users however you like (code here assumes a model named Task with a 'user' attribute):

```
def get_user_full_name_choices:
    return [(user, user.get_full_name()) for user in User.objects.all()]

class TaskAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
    user = forms.ChoiceField(choices=get_user_full_name_choices)
```

Then, tell your ModelAdmin class to use the new form:

```
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TaskAdminForm
```

Comment: what if the user list changes in the database?

Comment: @benzkji the sample here doesn't address this issue, it's also not meant to be used as is for exactly that reason. The ``choices`` argument to ``ChoiceField`` accepts both an iterable of two-tuples as shown here, as well as a callable which returns such an iterable. The latter choice is what you want for real production code.

Comment: so why not just provide a production ready code? rant on high level, I know ;-)

Comment: @benzkji I guess there's no real reason not to. The original point of the answer was to show that you can create your own form for your admin class, not so much how to provide the actual values (other than to show the structure required). Changing the source to a callable doesn't really make it any more complicated, and does provide a more production ready example. Thanks for the suggestion : )

Answer (score 2):

There is another choice:

```
USERS = [(user.id, user.get_full_name()) for user in User.objects.all()]
USERS.insert(0, ('', '----'))

class TaskAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TaskAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['user'].choices=USERS
```

Answer (score 1):

A more generic, verbose solution, using a ModelChoiceField as base. Avoids fiddling with querysets, just focusing on modifying the visible value in the dropdown.

1. create your own formfield:

```
class CustomLabelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
     def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         return "Howdy {}".format(obj.name)
```

2. use it either with formfield_for_dbfield (as in the link), or, more verbose, in your admin form:

```
class TaskAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = CustomLabelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all()
    class Meta:
        model = Task


# obviously, link it with your admin
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = TaskAdminForm
```

Answer (score 0):

By overriding [**formfield_for_foreignkey()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey), you can display **the combination of "first_name" and "last_name"** to **Django Admin** without creating **a custom "forms.ModelChoiceField"** and **a custom "forms.ModelForm"** as shown below:

```py
@admin.register(Task)
class TaskAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        formfield = super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == "user":
            formfield.label_from_instance = lambda obj: f'{obj.first_name} ({obj.last_name})'
        return formfield
```